# Can I make an R package available only to select users?

Tags: r, r-package

I'm developing several internal R packages for a team to make use of. However, I would like some of these packages to only be available to specific users. Is there any way of doing this within R, or do I need to resort to Windows directory locks?

Answer (score 4):

R "knows" where packages are based on directories listed in its library path -- `.libPaths()` shows it, and can alter it -- as can other commands, see `help(Startup)`.

You can have *some* control of what is available by adding to the `.libPaths()` directories which are mapped, or not, in the R startup -- when you can test for them in code. See `$RHOME/etc/Rprofile.site`. That way you are back to OS-level directory access and who gets to mount what...

In and by itself, R does not do authentication and permissioning *at all*.  Add-on products like RStudio (Server (Pro)) can, even with Active Directory and whatnot, but the Pro version is not free.

Comment: It should also be possible to install to a private git repository, and install the package using `devtools` into a library local to the user.

Comment: That's completely orthogonal. You talk about _installing_, I talk about _provisioning already installed packages_.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I'm storing all of my packages in the same location in .libPaths(), and want this .libPaths() to be the same for all users, I think the only real solution is to use Windows permissions in that case.